# Each symbol is assigned to indexes in Javascript after querying MongoDB in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, mongodb

I just realized that after querying the coordinates from MongoDB in PHP and assigning it in a javascript variable, that each of the characters has been assigned with indexes. Like if i `document.write(json[0])`, it prints the "[", `[1]` prints the next character "{", and so on. How do I convert this into normal JSON and assign it to a javascript variable?

Here's the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var json = "[" + '<?php $document = $collection->find([],['_id' => 0,'coordinates.coordinates' => 1]); foreach($document as $k => $row){ echo json_encode($row).","; }?>' + "]";
  document.write(json);
</script>
```

Here is the output data if I use `document.print(json)`

```
[{"coordinates":{"coordinates":[121.9197351,11.96795331]}},{"coordinates":{"coordinates":[121.9197351,11.96795331]}},{"coordinates":{"coordinates":[121.9197351,11.96795331]}},{"coordinates":{"coordinates":[121.9197351,11.96795331]}},]
```

I wanted it to work like this normal JSON inside a Javascript variable where I can utilize the coordinates normally like `json.coordinates.coordinates[1], json.coordinates.coordinates[0]`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var json = [{"coordinates":{"coordinates":[121.9197351,11.96795331]}},{"coordinates":{"coordinates":[121.9197351,11.96795331]}},{"coordinates":{"coordinates":[121.9197351,11.96795331]}},{"coordinates":{"coordinates":[121.9197351,11.96795331]}},];
</script>
```

Comment: You should instead output the html json assignment as an actual array and object. Doing `"["` is turning it into a literal string. Otherwise you need to use `JSON.parse()` on your `json` string.

Comment: Thanks for responding @IncredibleHat but im fairly new to these platforms (learned about 3 days ago). Would you mind telling me how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have this as your javascript variable assignment from php:

```
  var json = "[" + '<?php $document = $collection->find([],['_id' => 0,'coordinates.coordinates' => 1]); foreach($document as $k => $row){ echo json_encode($row).","; }?>' + "]";
```

Having it do `"[" +` is turning that into a string literal, and not actually a json object to use like you wish.

This would better be handled like so:

```
<?php
    $document = $collection->find([],['_id' => 0,'coordinates.coordinates' => 1]);
    $json = array();
    foreach($document as $row){ $json[] = $row; }
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var json = <?php echo json_encode($json);?>;
</script>
```

That puts all the rows into an array, and then outputs the whole array of rows as json into the javascript. That should then make the javascript var of `json` an actual json object to use like `json[0]-> coordinates`.

OR depending on the full makeup of `$document`, you could just do this:

```
<?php
    $document = $collection->find([],['_id' => 0,'coordinates.coordinates' => 1]);
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var json = <?php echo json_encode($document);?>;
</script>
```

Comment: Wow man you are a lifesaver! I thought I needed the opening and closing brackets and the commas for it to be considered a valid JSON. The first one seems to be working while the latter does not. Thank you @IncredibleHat

Comment: Well, you do if its 'coming from php' (as in, echoing out from php, it would need the brackets, which is what json_encode adds)... but once its in the html where javascript is and the web browser receives it, it needs to be clean and nothing but the brackets :)

Comment: Oh so the that's the purpose of json_encode. Interesting. I really apologize if it was this simple haha fairly new to these languages and I'm used to relational databases xD. Thanks again man @IncredibleHat

Comment: We all start somewhere. json_encode is a new wonderous tool I found out about a couple years ago... and it made so many things easier in my code where I had once been 'manually building and escaping strings and values' ... !!! =D Happy coding!

Comment: Also note that the original code was wrong, in that it would output a trailing comma in the JSON array (unless it was empty).